# ORA-12560: TNS: PROTOCOL ADAPTER ERROR PHP, ORACLE, WAMP

Tags: php, oracle, odbc, wamp, ora-12560

I am trying to connect to an oracle database on a remote server with php but it throws a warning: ora-12560 so I can't get connected with php but I can with toad for oracle, I am using odbc and I already set up my driver with microsoft odbc administrator:

I used odbc_connect(ConnectionString, UserID, UserPassword) in php

ConnectionString = Driver={Oracle en OraClient10g_home1};Server=xxx.xx.x.xxx;Port=1521;Database=xxxxxx;

I don't have access to the server where the database is located but I don't think the oracle service is down because I can connect with toad so it must be another thing. Here in my client I can make tnsping successful too.

Here is my tnsnames.ora

```
xxxxxx =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xxx.xx.x.xxx)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = xxxxxx)
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting to an Oracle RAC environment?

I have had issues like the one you describe when instance parameter local_listener is using a simplified notation like "dbnode-vip:1521" instead of "*(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=dbnode-vip)(PORT=1521))*".

You can test this scenario by accessing the vip-address directly:

xxxxxx = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ip-of-the-dbnode-vip-address)(PORT = 1521)) ) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = xxxxxx) ) )

Another possible solution would be to utilize a newer version of your Oracle Client software. 10g is like Windows XP. Who uses such old de-supported software?

Comment: I checked my local_listener and it was like: LISTENER = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xxx.xx.x.xxx)(PORT = 1521)) ) i think it must be another thing, but if other applications can connect like toad it must be a client side problem

Comment: Ask your admin to give you the output from this command: SQL> show parameter local_listener

Comment: it was solved long time ago, it was the connection string, there specific connection string for each driver, for oracle is: 'Driver={Oracle en OraClient10g_home1};SERVER= xxx.xx.x.xxx;UID=xxxxxxxxx;PWD=xxxxxxxxxxxxx;DBQ=xxxxxxxx'